# Hypothesis + selenium + pytest issue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, playwright, hypothesis-test

Not executing according to the set maximum number of times
and Generate the same data repeatedly

```py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from hypothesis import given, settings, HealthCheck, example, seed, strategies as st
import re


def test_search(keyword):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

        
        search_box = driver.find_element("name", "q")
        search_box.send_keys(keyword)

        
        search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        
        assert f"{keyword} - Google Search" in driver.title
        driver.quit()
    finally:
        
        driver.quit()

@settings(max_examples=3, database=None)
@seed(123)
@given(keyword=st.text(min_size=10, max_size=50))
def test_search_with_hypothesis(keyword):
    print("\nkeyword:", keyword)
    assert keyword is not None
    test_search(keyword)



@pytest.mark.parametrize("keyword", ["python", "selenium", "hypothesis"])
def test_fixed_keywords(keyword):
    test_search(keyword)

After execution:

demo\hy_selenium_pytest_demo.py E
keyword: 0000000000

keyword: ÄÖß=R

keyword: 9䔁116C

keyword: 9䔁116C

keyword: 䔁116C

keyword: 16C

Process finished with exit code -1
```

- `max_examples=3`,Generate more than 3 times
- The generated data has duplicates
- Hypothesis + playwright there are also similar issues

  ```
  @settings(max_examples=3, database=None)
  ```

I hope it's a random character, not

```
@example(keyword="python")
@example(keyword="selenium")
@example(keyword="hypothesis")
```